# Packages not persisting in Julia config on qBraid

Tags: quantum-computing, qbraid

Have successfully run the Julia packages in the qBraid Lab IDE. Now looking to persist the configuration, which seems to reset every time I run a new session. Is there a method for persistance?

Tried running the qBraid Lab IDE config with Julia packages but they reset after each session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default for `JULIA_DEPOT_PATH` in qBraid Lab is set to `/opt/.julia`. This is what causes the sessions to effectively reset as they are stored at the system level.

Update the depot path to save at the user level (in my example `/home/drya/.julia`) and you will be able to persist the additional packages, caches, configs, and other Julia updates.

`export JULIA_DEPOT_PATH="/home/drya/.julia:$JULIA_DEPOT_PATH"`